# Everything is ready for project . I have one doubt! I am using transmitter + Arduino *Uno*..and receiver + arduino *nano* will it work?

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-nano, nrf24l01+

Everything is ready for project except hardware!

I have one doubt!

I am planning to use transmitter of Arduino *Uno* and receiver of Arduino *Nano*.  Will it work? Both Uno and Nano obey for same program? (The transceivers used are  Nrf24lO1 pa+lna!)

Comment: only you know what the project is, so only you can determine if it will work

Comment: Uno and Nano have the same MCU and the same Arduino pin mapping. Nano is only a small Uno.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it will work, in much the same way that you can send an email from a Mac to a Windows PC. The type of PC doesn't matter as long as they use the same protocol. As you haven't shared any details in that direction, I would say that if you have coded correctly, then it will work.

Answer (score 0):

That cannot be determined until a much better description of your project is given. The parts you named are compatible with both processors. It could fail for a simple software mistook or a bad connection. Generally speaking the UNO and Nano are interchangeable electrically but not mechanically. The nano gives you two additional analog channels. Start by getting the RF to work, this probably will be the most problematic to get going. Use seperate power supplies for the RF devices.